# Stencil - is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: bigcommerce

I just got a new machine from IT and tried to install all the requirements on this page.

https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/prerequisites-windows

Windows 7 | Git for Windows | node-v4.6.1 x64 | Python 2.7.13 x64 | Visual Studio Community 2015

I followed the steps. I installed every software (the versions specified in the instruction, 64bit). I ran the command on the page. Everything was smooth except I couldn't run stencil command. It says "stencil" is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I did some research on it and it looks like it has to do with Environment Variables but I don't know where to start with..

What am I missing?

Comment: it sounds like a permission or install error. Try a fresh node install and I'd recommend nvm-windows too.

Comment: Fixed. I installed all of them once again and ran npm install. I think something went wrong during the previous installation, missing files, or corrupted files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a fresh node install and then npm install again. It sounds like a permission or installation issue.

Answer (score 0):

After installing both Python and Node.js, you should configure Python within the Node.js runtime environment by running this `npm` command:

```
npm config set python python2.7
```